# Angularjs - Calling a controller function inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use jQuery Sparkline charts with Angularjs. I have multiple charts to display, so I've decided to create a function in the controller and call it for each chart(directive).

**JS**

*controller*

```
.controller('sparklineCtrl', [function(){

     this.sparklineBar = function(id, values, height, barWidth, barColor, barSpacing) {
           $('.'+id).sparkline(values, {
                type: 'bar',
                height: height,
                barWidth: barWidth,
                barColor: barColor,
                barSpacing: barSpacing
           })
      }

}])
```

*directive*

```
.directive('sparklineBar', function(){

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                slBar: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.slBar('stats-bar', [6,4,8,6,5,6,7,8,3,5,9,5,8,4,3,6,8], '45px', 3, '#fff', 2);
            }
        }

    })
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="sparklineCtrl as spctrl">
      <div class="chart" id="stats-bar" data-sparkline-bar data-sl-bar="spctrl.sparklineBar()"></div>                                  
</div>
```

Running the above code there is no error in browser console but it's not rendering the chart at all. I don't know what is wrong in my code. When I try to place function's code directly inside directive, it's working.

```
.directive('sparklineBar', function(){

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                $('#stats-bar').sparkline([6,4,8,6,5,6,7,8,3,5,9,5,8,4,3,6,8], {
                    type: 'bar',
                    height: 45,
                    barWidth: 3,
                    barColor: '#fff',
                    barSpacing: 2
                })
            }
        }

    })
```

I don't want to use the above way as I need multiple charts. Please help me fix this using controller functions.

Comment: directive gives you acces to `element` which will be jQuery object when jQuery is included in page before angular. Use that instead of id selector. jQuery doesn't belong in controller, pass data into directive instead

Comment: Specify your controller in the directive. `controller: 'sparklineCtrl', controllerAs: 'spctrl'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to move the function logic into service/factory then using Injection to be used in your directive.

Example:

```
app.factory('sparkService', function () {
 var ss = {} ; 
 ss.slBar= function(id, values, height, barWidth, barColor, barSpacing) {
       $('.'+id).sparkline(values, {
            type: 'bar',
            height: height,
            barWidth: barWidth,
            barColor: barColor,
            barSpacing: barSpacing
       });
 };

 return ss;
}
```

While in directive

```
.directive('sparklineBar', ['sparkService',function(sparkService){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            slBar: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            sparkService.slBar('stats-bar', [6,4,8,6,5,6,7,8,3,5,9,5,8,4,3,6,8], '45px', 3, '#fff', 2);
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your method, but no luck. What should I need to call in HTML alongside with data-sparkline-bar? is it something like data-sl-bar='....' ?

Comment: Please ignore my reply above, it's working perfectly. Thank you very much again.